# Crash popups with XCode 12 and simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator, xcode12

With Xcode 12 and iOS Simulators, Xcode doesn't crash but these are the errors I get every few hours, not always all but always some of them

```
CalendarWidgetAppExtension quit unexpectedly.
parsecd quit unexpectedly.
healthappd quit unexpectedly.
NewsTag quit unexpectedly.
NewsToday2 quit unexpectedly.
bulletindistributord quit unexpectedly.
ProtectedCloudKeySyncing quit unexpectedly.
```

Somebody knows what is going on ?

Comment: These are obviously Simulator bugs that Apple is responsible for fixing. Continue to report them (click on the report button). In the mean time, if you don't anticipate being affected by the bits that are broken then follow @mike.stalker's advice below and/or use a device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What helped to me:

1. Download [Additional Tools for Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=Additional%20Tools%20for%20Xcode)
   [image: Additional Tools for Xcode]
2. Launch Utilities/CrashReporterPrefs
   [image: Utilities/CrashReporterPrefs]
3. Set Crash Reporter to the "Basic" mode.
   [image: Crash Reporter to the "Basic" mode]
4. Restart (quitting and launching only Xcode did not helped, but OS restart did)